# How to include .NET classes in VBA?

Tags: .net, vba, outlook

I am new to VBA and now want to create code for Outlook that sends a JSON message. It does not compile.

> Compile error: expected end of statement

or

> Compile error: expected =

This is the code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Sub SendMessage(mail As MailItem)
    Dim uri As New Uri("http://myip:9050/message")

    Dim req As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(uri)
    req.Method = "PUT"
    req.Accept = "application/json;"
    req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8"

    Dim jsonString As String = "{ ""message"" : """ + mail + """ }"
    Dim jsonDataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString)
    req.ContentLength = jsonDataBytes.Length

    Dim stream As IO.Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
    stream.Write(jsonDataBytes, 0, jsonDataBytes.Length)
    stream.Close()

    req.GetResponse()

End Sub
```

Or visually:

[image: visual code]

How can I get this too work?

Comment: You can write .net COM Outlook Addin. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194126/Creating-an-Outlook-Add-In then you'll be able to use it in Outlook

Comment: Thanks. For now, I am using VBA to simply call a PowerShell script as follows `Call Shell("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\Scripts\Send-Message.ps1 -Message test from outlook", 1)`. The COM module would be better and more reusable, maybe later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA and .Net are different worlds.

In that case I'd suggest developing an Outlook add-in (for example, VSTO based) where you can use all BCL classes. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started quickly.

Also you may find the [Outlook Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386094.aspx) section in MSDN helpful.